# Output function value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to output SVG icons stored in an array of objects.

The SVG icons are stored in functional components. Then their values are stored in an array of objects.

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/rexwebmedia/pen/mdBMRqE

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

```js
function IconA() {
  return (
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bag" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path d="M8 1a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.5 2.5V4h-5v-.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 8 1zm3.5 3v-.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 0-7 0V4H1v10a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h-3.5zM2 5h12v9a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V5z" />
    </svg>
  );
}

function IconB() {
  return (
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bookmark" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path d="M2 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h8a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.777.416L8 13.101l-5.223 2.815A.5.5 0 0 1 2 15.5V2zm2-1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v12.566l4.723-2.482a.5.5 0 0 1 .554 0L13 14.566V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H4z" />
    </svg>
  );
}

const iconList = [
  { icon: IconA, title: "Icon A" },
  { icon: IconB, title: "Icon B" }
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      Output value of function in object
      <ul>
        {iconList.map((item) => {
          return (
            <li>
              {item.icon} - {item.title}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Change `{item.icon}` to `{item.icon()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the functions IconA and IconB that render the icon. Try like this:

```
    {iconList.map((item) => {
      return (
        <li>
          {item.icon()} - {item.title}
        </li>
      );
    })}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the reply.

Answer (score 0):

In the above snipped as @Ivo already mentioned you are not calling the function, so by invoking the function you can render it.

Or another way will be

```
 {iconList.map((item) => {
      const Icon = item.icon;
      return (
        <li>
          <Icon /> - {item.title}
        </li>
      );
    })}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/johnthomas1993/pen/ExwvWPa)